# Updating one to one model using form in Django

Tags: python, django

I am very new to Python and Django and am stuck with this problem , which I think should be very simple to solve.

model.py

```
class UserDetails(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    billingAddress = AddressField(related_name='+',blank =True ) # Used django-address https://pypi.org/project/django-address/
    shippingAddress = AddressField(related_name='+',blank =True)
```

forms.py

```
class AddressForm(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
          model = UserDetails
          exclude = ['user']
```

views.py

```
def address(request):
    form = AddressForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():  
        zipCode = request.POST.get("ZipCode","")
        form = AddressForm(data=request.POST)
        detailForm = form.save(commit = False)
        detailForm.user = request.user
        baddressDict = {'raw':request.POST.get("billingAddress","")+", " + zipCode, 'postal_code': zipCode,}
        saddressDict = {'raw':request.POST.get("shippingAddress","")+", " + zipCode, 'postal_code': zipCode,}
        detailForm.billingAddress = baddressDict
        detailForm.shippingAddress = saddressDict
        detailForm.save()
    else:
        form = AddressForm()
    return render(request,'showcase/address.html',{'form': form})
```

address.html

```
<form action="." method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="text" name="ZipCode" value="Vip Code" >
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" >
</form>
```

What I am trying to do it update the shipping & Billing address for current user.
The first time I am doing this it works but the second time it gives

> UNIQUE constraint failed: showcase_userdetails.user_id

which obviously is cause it trying to add another row in the DB.

**How do i make sure it updates and not insert?**

Thanks, 
Gourav

Comment: You need to pass the instance you want to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simply, [you have to pass an existing instance of your model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/):

```
def edit_address(request):
    user = request.user
    try:
        address_instance = UserDetail.objects.get(user=user)
    except UserDetail.DoesNotExist:
        address_instance = None

    if request.method == 'POST':  
        form = AddressForm(request.POST, instance=address_instance)
        if form.is_valid(): 

            details = form.save(commit=False)
            # You should really let the form takes care of all this,
            # and you should DEFINITLY NOT use unsanitized data from
            # request.POST - the whole point of forms is to make sure
            # your user inputs are properly sanitized...
            details.user = request.user
            # etc
    else:
        # passing it for the GET part too so the user
        # can see the already existing data (if any)
        form = AddressForm(instance=address_instance)

    return render(request,'showcase/address.html',{'form': form})
```

Comment: It worked thanks. Also the reason I have used cant only use form because the adddressfield class which i am using only has 1 property called address.To get/set the others you have to create a dict and update in it and hence I have to use data from Post.

Comment: @GouravSinha I just had a look at django-address, and there definitly are a better ways - ie using a formset of ModelForms for Address model, or using [the provided form](https://github.com/furious-luke/django-address#forms), or just writing your own (non-model) Form, etc. In all cases, you want to use a Form for user inputs validation and sanitization, and you don't want to leak all this stuff into your views. The less code in your views, the better... (hint: forms can be used outside views - think data import from a csv or so -, forms don't need `requests` to be unittested, etc).

Comment: @GouravSinha hmm yes indeed, your user has two addresse. You'll have to replace `UserDetail.objects.get(...)` with either `user.billingAddress` or `user.shippingAddress` I guess, but since this app is doing things in a rather non-standard way (ie providing a ForeignKey subclass with some undocumented magic) I just can't garantee this will work out of the box either. But well, at worse it's open source so you can always check the source code to find out.

Comment: Sorry I deleted the comment just to tell others the problem with above code is that is throws error get() returned more than one Address -- it returned 2!, as it has two address in the Model (Shipping and Billing)

Comment: @ bruno desthuilliers thanks for your help, I have decided to use my own address model as addressfield is just making things more difficult.